# Switch-Case pattern for non-constant types

Tags: c#

**Edit**: Following answers, I modified my code, and wrote [an other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213106/switch-case-pattern-for-non-constant-types-part-2).

---

## History

Recently, I (stupidly) tried to make a switch on `myObj.GetType()`. Of course, it didn't work. Then I made an ugly (this is subjective) `if ... else if ... else if ... else ...` list.
I ask myself if I couldn't make something to keep the `switch-case` architecture, and then I started experienced things.

## Expected

To keep the structure of a *real* `switch-case`, I want to use it in this way:

```
Switch(myInt)
    .Case(1, EqualsOneMethod)
    .Case(2, EqualsTwoMethod)
    .CaseWhen(i => i <= 0, NullOrNegativeMethod)
    .Default(DefaultMethod);
```

---

```
static void EqualsOneMethod() { ... }
static void EqualsTwoMethod() { ... }
static void NullOrNegativeMethod() { ... }
static void DefaultMethod() { ... }
```

## Code

Everything starts with this interface:

```
public interface ISwitchCase<T>
{
    ISwitchCase<T> Case(T value, Action action);
    ISwitchCase<T> Case(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action action);
    ISwitchCase<T> CaseWhen(Predicate<T> predicate, Action action);
    void Default(Action action);
}
```

---

The *normal* implementation is this one:

```
internal class SwitchCase<T> : ISwitchCase<T>
{
    private T Value { get; }

    public SwitchCase(T value) { Value = value; }

    public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T value, Action action)
    {
        if (Value is IEquatable<T>)
            return CaseWhen(t => ((IEquatable<T>)t).Equals(value), action);

        if (value is IEquatable<T>)
            return CaseWhen(t => ((IEquatable<T>)value).Equals(t), action);

        return Case(value, EqualityComparer<T>.Default, action);
    }

    public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action action)
    {
        return CaseWhen(t => comparer.Equals(Value, value), action);
    }

    public ISwitchCase<T> CaseWhen(Predicate<T> predicate, Action action)
    {
        if (predicate(Value))
        {
            action();
            return EmptySwitchCase<T>.Instance;
        }

        return this;
    }

    public void Default(Action action) =>
        action();
}
```

---

Whenever a case fullfils its predicate, it returns an `EmptySwitchCase`, which is the following:

```
internal class EmptySwitchCase<T> : ISwitchCase<T>
{
    public static EmptySwitchCase<T> Instance { get; }

    static EmptySwitchCase() { Instance = new EmptySwitchCase<T>(); }

    private EmptySwitchCase() { }

    public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T value, Action action) => this;

    public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action action) => this;

    public ISwitchCase<T> CaseWhen(Predicate<T> predicate, Action action) => this;

    public void Default(Action action) { }
}
```

Thanks to this `EmptySwitchCase`, once a `case` is *executed*, no other `case` / `default` will be triggered.

---

Finally, as all these classes are `internal`, a simple `static class` is used as a facade:

```
public static class Bar // couldn't find a correct name...
{
    public static ISwitchCase<T> Switch<T>(T value) => new SwitchCase<T>(value);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add all code and replace the `...` in `EqualsOneMethod` etc. with actual implementations?

Comment: @t3chb0t: To what end? OP's question focuses on the structure used to get to those methods, regardless of what each method body entails.

Comment: Switching on type is possible nowadays with [pattern matching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching).

Comment: Minor nitpick: you are not posting buildable code, as `.CaseWhen(i <= 0, NullOrNegativeMethod)` is not syntactically valid (the first parameter passed in a boolean whereas `CaseWhen` expects a `Predicate`). Also, your `Switch` class doesn't actually have a `CaseWhen` method, so there are several issues at play here. This code does not work.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Consider posting a follow-up question instead, after waiting at least 24h. More answers may be incoming.

Comment: @Mast: Checking the revision history, the only changes OP made are changes that fix the code to make it buildable. That's not the same as updating the answer based on the given review; OP was simply fixing the code that still needs to be reviewed.

Comment: @Flater Since the changes appear to be based on your answer, we can't accept the edits even partly invalidating said answer. If the code was bugged beyond review without the edit, it shouldn't have been answered *before* the edit. In this case, I highly recommend leaving this question be and let OP and interested reviewers put their effort in the next question. Just leave this one be.

Comment: @Mast: The changes are based on my comment, not on my answer. I'll remove the first mention from my answer because it was indeed a typo on OP's part, but blocking the question edit here is counterproductive. I fully agree with the rule you're pointing to but it simply does not apply to the changes OP made.

Comment: @Flater This potentially increases the mess since in the meantime another answer has been posted. However, I don't know whether this actually happened, so while I completely disagree with your actions, I won't follow up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Case(2, EqualsTwoMethod)
.CaseWhen(i <= 0, NullOrNegativeMethod)
```

For consistency's sake, I'd suggest to always keep using the predicate:

```
.CaseWhen(i => i == 2, EqualsTwoMethod)
.CaseWhen(i => i <= 0, NullOrNegativeMethod)
```

It seems a bit counterintuitive that you'd create a custom method for equality checks, but then use a much broader predicate that handles basically any other boolean evaluation.

---

The biggest issue I have here is that you're not leveraging OOP. Your current usage suggests that you rebuild a new `Switch` every time you wish to use it for execution. But since the entire switch is built using constant or hardcoded expressions, it makes no sense to have to rebuild it every time.

While I do understand that you're trying to mimic the syntax of an actual `switch` as closely as possible, this is going to cause performance issues in iterative loops. Simply put:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Switch(i)
        .Case(1, EqualsOneMethod)
        .Case(2, EqualsTwoMethod)
        .CaseWhen(i <= 0, NullOrNegativeMethod)
        .Default(DefaultMethod);
}
```

You will have instantiated 10 `Switch` objects.

Instead, how about you create your `Switch` case once and then reuse it? The only difference is that you then have to pass `myInt` *after* you've created the switch:

```
var mySwitch = (new Switch<int>())
                .CaseWhen(i => i == 1, EqualsOneMethod)
                .CaseWhen(i => i == 2, EqualsTwoMethod)
                .CaseWhen(i => i <= 0, NullOrNegativeMethod)
                .Default(DefaultMethod);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    mySwitch.EvaluateFor(i);
}
```

This means that you first build your switch (once), and then reuse it as many times as you need. This leverages OOP much better because you are not consuming and releasing switch objects for every single check you want to do.

Comment: I do not like the _only predicate_ choice, because this is what I want to avoid with the `if ... else if ... else ...` method. I do not want to manually write `.CaseWhen(type => type == typeof(MyClass))`, which is the same thing that (maybe _worse than_) `if (myType == typeof(MyClass))`. I want to use it in this way: `Switch(myType) .Case(typeof(String),StringMethod) .Case(typeof(int),IntMethod) .Default(DefaultMethod)`.

Comment: Else, I understand your point and totally agree with it, thank you for your answer! I do not accept it for now but it will probably be in a near future.

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda: Fair enough about not wanting to always use the predicate, but I would expect to see more than just equality checks then. You didn't actually develop a type matching case in your example, so my review cannot be based on its (non)existence. Also, I would suggest doing `Case<string>(StringMethod)` to create a slightly cleaner syntax.

Comment: I might be misunderstood, I do not want it to work _only_ with `Type`, so your suggestion doesn't work. I almost finished re-building the whole thing, (I hope that) I'll make my question more precise about what I really want.

Answer (score 4):

The co-occurrence of `Value` and `value` in the same methods is irritating and likely to lead to bugs: I would rename `value` to `query` or something like that (and shall call `value` by `query` for the rest of this answer in the interests of not making any mistakes myself).

---

I was initially dubious of Flater's suggestion that creating the `SwitchCase` objects would be a problem given all the predicates flying around, so I looked at the memory characteristics of his example loop (only with a few more zeros on the end), and saw that I was completely wrong:

[image]

Note all the predicates and boxed `int`s (always a bad sign). All those predicates are not the ones the caller wrote: those are predicates created by the `Case(T, ...)` methods, and all the `Int32`s are integers being boxed so they can be cast as `IEquatable<int>`. If you change Flater's code to one which only uses the `Case(Predicate<T>, ...)` overload, everything disappears with the exception of the `SwitchCase`s (the caller's predicates are reused), and as Flater says, you can remove those too by caching and improve the method memory characteristics dramatically.

---

Now to diverge from the code itself... there may be little point in your `if (Value is IEquatable<T>)` condition, since the `EqualityComparer` will do that for you. The only thing it gives you, is that it will use `T`'s implementation of `IEquatable<T>` by default rather than `query`'s: this sort of thing needs to carefully documented, because it could cause someone down the line no-end of confusion when they try to 'override' the comparison by implementing `IEquatable<T>` in a super-class of `T`, only to have it ignored. This feels the wrong way round to me; however, personally I wouldn't do the check for either, and would solely depend on the `EqualityComparer` (and maybe a comparer passed to the constructor). If I did want to use `query`'s implementation, then I probably ought to know either that it has an implementation to use (and when it will be used), in which case the caller can decide if they want to use it or not. I'd rather provide a performant version with statically determinable behaviour:

```cs
public ISwitchCase<T> Case<S>(S query, Action action) where S : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (query.Equals(Value))
    {
        action();
        return EmptySwitchCase<T>.Instance;
    }

    return this;
}
```

Such a method also has the advantage of being efficient when handling `structs`, as it doesn't involve any boxing. I've also in-lined the conditional logic, because it avoids the allocation of the `Predicate<T>` and its body (which can't be reused).

This doesn't solve the boxing `int` problem in Flater's example, because the `Case(T, etc.)` overloads are better, but if you replace those with these, you can prevent any repetitive allocations occurring when these methods are called.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Compares the query and internal value using the DefaultEqualityComparer, and invokes the given action if they match
/// </summary>
public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T query, Action action)
{
    return Case(query, EqualityComparer<T>.Default, action);
}

/// <summary>
/// Compares the query and internal value using the given comparer, and invokes the given action if they match
/// </summary>
public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T query, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action action)
{
    if (comparer.Equals(Value, query))
    {
        action();
        return EmptySwitchCase<T>.Instance;
    }

    return this;
}
```

Obviously it's your decision what your API does, and it is important to stress that the behaviour is different like this, but that the behaviour was unclear before. With the added inline documentation, the new behaviour is clear and completely transparent at compile time. The difference is that that a value which provides an alternative implementation of `IEquatable<T>` will only be compared using this implementation if it is not a `T` and it can be determined at compile time that it is `IEquatable<T>`. I'd make a case for this behaviour being more 'intuitive', because it become equivalent to using a predicate of the form `v => query.Equals(v)` when `query` is not of type `T`. Without a `: T` constraint, this means that stuff which is comparable to `T` without necessarily being a `T` can also be used, which may or may nor be desirable.

---

Naturally, it is not nice having many methods implementing the `if (predicate(Value))` logic, so I'd be inclined to put this login in a simple `private ISwitchCase<T> Case(bool condition, Action action)`, essentially replacing your current `Case(Predicate<T>, etc.)` in this role. If you want to keep the dynamic `IEquatable<T>` behaviour, then you can still rid yourself of all the anonymous methods by using such a method instead of deferring everything to `Case(Predicate<T>, etc.)`. For example:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Compares the query with the internal value, first trying to use implementation of `IEquatable&lt;t&gt;` provided by the internal value, then that provided by the query, falling back to the DefaultComparer otherwise
/// </summary>
public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T query, Action action)
{
    if (Value is IEquatable<T>)
        return Case(((IEquatable<T>)Value).Equals(query), action);

    if (query is IEquatable<T>)
        return Case(((IEquatable<T>)query).Equals(Value), action);

    return Case(query, EqualityComparer<T>.Default, action);
}

/// <summary>
/// Compares the query and internal value using the given comparer, and calls the given action if they match
/// </summary>
public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T query, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action action)
{
        return Case(comparer.Equals(Value, query), action);
}

/// <summary>
/// Invokes the given action if the condition is true
/// </summary>
private ISwitchCase<T> Case(bool condition, Action action)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        action();
        return EmptySwitchCase<T>.Instance;
    }

    return this;
}
```

Or, more tidily (using pattern matching):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Compares the query with the internal value, first trying to use implementation of `IEquatable&lt;t&gt;` provided by the internal value, then that provided by the query, falling back to the DefaultComparer otherwise
/// </summary>
public ISwitchCase<T> Case(T query, Action action)
{
    if (Value is IEquatable<T> v)
        return Case(v.Equals(query), action);

    if (query is IEquatable<T> q)
        return Case(q.Equals(Value), action);

    return Case(query, EqualityComparer<T>.Default, action);
}
```

Note the inline documentation, which should appear on the `interface`.

Comment: I know I should avoid only thanking people, but as I can only validate one answer, I "only" up voted yours, so I want to thank you for your analysis. I understood your point about documentation and my equality checks. I disabled this in my second version. Also, about your `Case(bool, Action)` idea, I didn't manage to build it in my second version, mostly because of @Flater recommandation to build switch before any evaluation. As the switch now can have multiple values, your solution is (to my eyes at least) impossible.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what did you use to get this diagram? How can I understand it?

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda [ClrProfiler](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273) in 'allocations' mode (diagram is the Allocation Graph). It's a bit finicky, but very useful for finding memory leaks and excess allocations. The Allocation Graph shows a call-tree, with the roots being types of object, indicating which methods created which objects. In-lining and other optimisations can make them misleading/difficult to interpret sometimes, but that's true with any tool.