# Switch-Case pattern for non-constant types (part 2)

Tags: c#

You can find the "part 1" [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213049/switch-case-pattern-for-non-constant-types).

---

## 1. Objectives

The main goal of this post is to build a switch-like structure, which allows to use non-constant Type (e.g. `Type`, `Drawing.Point`, or any custom type). This implementation should understand three different cases:

- Equality case (like a regular case statement)
- 'Predicate' case (like a `case n when n < 0`)
- Default case (like a regular default statement)

This custom `switch` must have the exact same **outputs** that a regular `switch`.

## 2. Usage

As [@Flater](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31886/flater) pointed it out [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213055/182398), the switch should be created first, and should be able to evaluate multiple values. This is an example of what I want:

```
var mySwitch = Bar.Switch<Response>()
    .CaseWhen(r => r.Id < 0, ErrorMethod)
    .Case(Response.OK, OkMethod)
    .Case(Response.Warning, WarningMethod)
    .Case(null, NullMethod)
    .Default(DefaultMethod);

var response = Client.Post(content);
mySwitch.EvaluateFor(response);
```

## 3. Implementation

[image: Classes diagram]

### 3.a. Public interfaces

```
/// <summary>
/// Simulates an evaluable-only switch
/// </summary>
public interface IEvaluable<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the switch with the given value, and executes the first case that matches this value, if any
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value used to execute the switch</param>
    void EvaluateFor(T value);
}
```

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Simulates a switch instruction
/// </summary>
public interface ISwitch<T> : IEvaluable<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a case to the switch (at the end), and return the aforesaid switch
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">Value that will be tested for equality, using default EqualityComparer</param>
    /// <param name="action">Action to perform if case matches</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ISwitch<T> Case(T query, Action action);

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a case to the switch (at the end), and return the aforesaid switch
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">Predicate that will test the value</param>
    /// <param name="action">Action to perform if case matches</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ISwitch<T> CaseWhen(Predicate<T> predicate, Action action);

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a default-case to the switch (at the end), and return the aforesaid (evaluable-only) switch
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">Action to perform if no case matches before</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEvaluable<T> Default(Action action);
}
```

### 3.b. Internal interfaces

```
internal interface IHasNextCase<T>
{
    void Append(ICase<T> nextCase);
}

internal interface ICase<T> : IHasNextCase<T>
{
    void EvaluateFor(T value);
}
```

### 3.c. Switch section

```
internal abstract class SwitchCaseBase<T> : IEvaluable<T>, IHasNextCase<T>
{
    protected ICase<T> Next { get; set; }

    public virtual void Append(ICase<T> nextCase)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(Next, null))
            Next = nextCase;
        else
            Next.Append(nextCase);
    }

    public abstract void EvaluateFor(T value);
}

internal sealed class Switch<T> : SwitchCaseBase<T>, ISwitch<T>
{
    IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer { get; }

    internal Switch() { Comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default; }
    internal Switch(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) { Comparer = comparer; }

    public ISwitch<T> Case(T query, Action action)
    {
        Append(new Case<T>(query, Comparer, action));
        return this;
    }

    public ISwitch<T> CaseWhen(Predicate<T> predicate, Action action)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(predicate, null)) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

        Append(new CaseWhen<T>(predicate, action));
        return this;
    }

    public IEvaluable<T> Default(Action action)
    {
        Append(new Default<T>(action));
        return this;
    }

    public override void EvaluateFor(T value) =>
        Next?.EvaluateFor(value);
}
```

### 3.d. Case section

```
internal abstract class CaseBase<T> : SwitchCaseBase<T>, ICase<T>
{
    protected Action Action { get; }

    internal CaseBase(Action action)
    { Action = action; }

    protected void Execute() =>
        Action?.Invoke();
}

internal sealed class Case<T> : CaseBase<T>
{
    private T Query { get; }
    private IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer { get; }

    internal Case(T query, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Action action)
        : base(action)
    {
        Query = query;
        Comparer = comparer;
    }

    public override void EvaluateFor(T value)
    {
        if (Comparer.Equals(Query, value))
            Execute();
        else
            Next?.EvaluateFor(value);
    }
}

internal sealed class CaseWhen<T> : CaseBase<T>
{
    Predicate<T> Predicate { get; }

    internal CaseWhen(Predicate<T> predicate, Action action)
        : base(action)
    { Predicate = predicate; }

    public override void EvaluateFor(T value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Predicate(value))
            {
                Execute();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch { }

        Next?.EvaluateFor(value);
    }
}

internal sealed class Default<T> : CaseBase<T>
{
    internal Default(Action action)
        : base(action)
    { }

    // throws an error because after a default,
    // switch shouldn't be able to add another case
    public override void Append(ICase<T> nextCase)
    { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }

    public override void EvaluateFor(T value) =>
        Execute();
}
```

### 3.e. Public facade

```
public static class Bar // still no idea about how to name this class... 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a simulated switch instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The aforesaid switch</returns>
    public static ISwitch<T> Switch<T>() => new Switch<T>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a simulated switch instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comparer">Comparer used to compare evaluated-value and case-value</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ISwitch<T> Switch<T>(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) => new Switch<T>(comparer);
}
```

## 4. Example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mySwitch = Bar.Switch<Response>()
            .CaseWhen(r => r.Id < 0, ErrorMethod)
            .Case(Response.OK, OkMethod)
            .Case(Response.Warning, WarningMethod)
            .Case(null, NullMethod)
            .Default(DefaultMethod);

        for (int content = -10; content < 10; content++)
        {
            var response = Client.Post(content);
            mySwitch.EvaluateFor(response);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ErrorMethod() { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("Error, your content is badly formatted"); }
    static void OkMethod() { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; Console.WriteLine("OK"); }
    static void WarningMethod() { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow; Console.WriteLine("Warning, there might be a problem"); }
    static void NullMethod() { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray; Console.WriteLine("Timeout, please check your connection"); }
    static void DefaultMethod() { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan; Console.WriteLine("Unknown response, please check the logs"); }

    static class Client
    {
        public static Response Post(int content)
        {
            if (content % 7 == 0)
                return null;
            if (content % 5 == 0)
                return Response.Warning;
            if (content % 3 == 0)
                return Response.OK;
            if (content % 2 == 0)
                return new Response(content, "Hello");
            return new Response(-content, "Error");
        }
    }

    class Response : IEquatable<Response>
    {
        public static readonly Response OK = new Response(0, "OK");
        public static readonly Response Warning = new Response(1, "Warning");

        public int Id { get; }
        public string Message { get; }

        public Response(int id, string message)
        {
            Id = id;
            Message = message;
        }

        public bool Equals(Response other) =>
            other.Id == Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I still don't like this implementation because:

- it's waaaay to complex
- it isn't easily extendable
- doesn't provide the basic `switch` logic one expects from it, this is, it cannot fall through multiple cases
- it requires to repeat the same logic multiple times with every `EvaluateFor`

---

What you have build is a `SwitchBuilder` that you also should name like that. I prefer to create and use it where it belongs e.g. inside a loop and not before so I suggest a much simpler approach with a `readonly struct`.

---

What you need is a single interface for the value and a continuation flag like:

```
public interface ISwitch<T>
{
    T Value { get; }

    bool CanEvaluateNext { get; }
}
```

an `internal readonly struct` that implements it and doesn't cost a penny to create so it can be used it loops:

```
internal readonly struct Switch<T> : ISwitch<T>
{
    public Switch(T value, bool canEvaluateNext)
    {
        Value = value;
        CanEvaluateNext = canEvaluateNext;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public bool CanEvaluateNext { get; }
}
```

a single core extension for the interface that you'll use to implement every other convenience extension like `Default`, `CaseWhen` or whatever you like using custom comparers etc. You don't need anything else and you can build every other API by calling this extension (which is your homework).

```
public static class SwitchExtensions
{
    public static ISwitch<T> Case<T>(this ISwitch<T> @switch, Predicate<T> predicate, Action<T> action, bool canEvaluateNext)
    {
        if (!@switch.CanEvaluateNext)
        {
            return @switch;
        }

        if (predicate(@switch.Value))
        {
            action(@switch.Value);
            return new Switch<T>(@switch.Value, canEvaluateNext);
        }
        else
        {
            return @switch;
        }
    }
}
```

Since `Switch<T>` is internal you'll need a  helper-factory-class for a nice fluent syntax:

```
public static class Switch
{
    public static ISwitch<T> For<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Switch<T>(value, false);
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
Switch
    .For(5)
    .Case(x => x == 4, x => Console.WriteLine(x), false) // nope
    .Case(x => x == 5, x => Console.WriteLine(x), false) // 5
    .Case(x => x == 6, x => Console.WriteLine(x), false); // nope
```

or

```
Switch
    .For(5)
    .Case(x => x == 4, x => Console.WriteLine(x), true) // nope
    .Case(x => x == 5, x => Console.WriteLine(x), true) // 5
    .Case(x => x < 6, x => Console.WriteLine(x), true); // 5
```

Comment: Does a basic `switch` "can fall through multiple cases"? Tell me if I'm wrong, but at the end of a `case`, we have to choose between `break`, `return` or `goto`, don't we? So the only way to "fall through multiple cases" is by using `goto`?

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda no, you don't have to use `break`, it's optional, you can have muliple `case`s and only one `break`.

Comment: But for this, the first `case`s have to be _empty_? Like `switch(x) { case 1: case 2: case 3: doSomething(); break; }`?

Comment: Following [Eric Lippert answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3049601/9757968), there is no "fall-through" in C#, but one statement-list can have multiple case-labels. To do so, I should add an extension with this signature: `Case<T>(this ISwitch<T> @switch, IEnumerable<Predicate<T>> predicates, Action action)`.

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda potato-potahto ;-] You can add as many extensions as you want as long as you don't just copy paste them but reuse one of two with the most generic signature to create those with more convenient ones that cover the most common use-cases.

Answer (score -1):

I saw a mistake, in the `CaseWhen.EvaluateFor` method. If an exception is thrown in the `Execute()` part, this exception will be caught. Instead, I should have write:

```
public override void EvaluateFor(T value)
{
    bool success;

    try
    { success = Predicate(value); }
    catch
    { success = false; }

    if (success)
        Execute();
    else
        Next?.EvaluateFor(value);
}
```

I think I also should test if `comparer` is not null here:

```
public static ISwitch<T> Switch<T>(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(comparer, null)) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");

    return new Switch<T>(comparer);
}
```

Comment: I know you were told not to edit your initial post after receiving answers.  You could have have edited the post with the above, but since it is now a posted answer, you are back to not being allowed to update your initial post.

Comment: @RickDavin In some cases both options are also viable, in this case I think it's a reasonable answer too.